# Proof of im/possibility of constructing any fractal by iterated function systems?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, fractals

Well the question is as simple as that and what I really want to see is if there is a mathematical proof that can tell whether every fractal(object of any non-integer dimension) can be constructed by iterated function systems(such as in p.55 of [this](http://www.sti.uniurb.it/events/sfm13ds/slides/edalat.pdf)). A reference will be very helpful.

EDIT: 1) changed 'iterated maps' -> iterated functions systems
      2) a similar question was asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74458/is-there-some-known-way-to-create-the-mandelbrot-set-the-boundary-with-an-ite?rq=1)
      3) An article suggesting a [counter-example](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/228394609_A_LOCALLY_CONNECTED_CONTINUUM_WHICH_IS_NOT_AN_IFS_ATTRACTOR?ev=auth_pub) is suggested in the comments below

Comment: That's all very fine, but *what* is a fractal ? Also what is to be considered "iterative sequence of one underlying shape" ? For instance Julia sets (we can agree *those* enter the "fractal" realm) are not affine self-similar, but they do have some non-linear self-similarity properties. Where do you draw the line ? I'm afraid you won't be able to phrase your question in a mathematically precise way...

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier Thanks for quick asking. What I really want to know is if every object of fractal dimension can be constructed by an iterative map regardless of the map being linear or not.

Comment: Then I recommend you should rewrite your question based on that definition of a "fractal". Also your "PS" seems irrelevant to me.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier I have edited the question to make it more general.

Comment: As they say, it depends on what you mean by fractal, and also on what you mean by self-similar.

Comment: This depends on what constraints you have on your definition of "map".  There is a basic set-theoretic obstruction, namely that there are too many objects fractional dimension to come from things like continuous maps of euclidean space.

Comment: I have edited my answer. I am most certain that the answer to any of the permutations of your question is NO.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not true. For example, all fractals generated from an Iterated function System, (IFS), are self-similar in the sense that the fractal is the union of the images of the fractal itself, *under several maps*.
[See Hutchinson operator.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hutchinson_operator)

The classical Julia fractals can be interpreted in this manner, where the two branches of the inverse of $z \to z^2+c$ are used.

Then, there are the [random midpoint displacement fractals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond-square_algorithm)
which are self-similar in a much weaker sense than above, since these fractals involve random choices.

Not all fractals are given by iterating a map (I prefer to call these types of fractals discrete); some fractals are constructed using continuous methods, such as the [Lorenz attractor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system). But note, this fractal can be approximated using iteration of a set of maps.

New Edit: The Mandelbrot fractal cannot (most likely) be constructed via IFS, (I have asked this question before here on MO).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please see my reply for Qiaochu Yuan for clarification of the question.

Comment: @Ten: Ok, I added a response.

Comment: Thanks again. So still is it possible to construct any fractal by iteration?(since existence of a construct by continuous method does not preclude the existence of an iterative procedure, unless one gives a proof otherwise)

Comment: You need to define what you mean by iteration, and what you mean by map. The midpoint displacement fractal is based on a random process, so there is no iteration of deterministic maps.

Comment: I have made the question more precise.

Comment: Can you please link where you've asked about it?

Comment: It was linked under "Related" to the right here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/74458/is-there-some-known-way-to-create-the-mandelbrot-set-the-boundary-with-an-ite?rq=1

Comment: See also MR1686674 (2000j:28008) 
Kwieciński, Michał(PL-JAGL)
A locally connected continuum which is not an IFS attractor. (English summary)
Bull. Polish Acad. Sci. Math. 47 (1999), no. 2, 127–132.

Comment: Per, @MargaretFriedland Thanks for the link and the article. I have added this piece of info/counter example in the original post.